# Summing values in multiple lines separated by comma from text file in Python

Tags: python

I want to add values from each line separated by comma. For example ,
If my input file contents are:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The output should be:

```
6
15
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('untitled6.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        sum(map(int,open('untitled6.txt').readline().split(',')))
```

The output should be written in a new file like this:

```
6
15
```

Comment: Why do you open the file twice? `print(sum(map(int, line.split(','))))`

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a couple of problems:

- you open the file once, but you do not really use it
- you never `print()` the result of the `sum()`.

Fixing these would make your code work:

```
with open('untitled6.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        print(sum(map(int, line.split(','))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```py
with open('untitled6.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        print(sum([int(v) for v in line.split(',')]))
```

**Output**

```
6
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open the file twice, use the lines you extract from `istr`:

```
with open('untitled6.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        print(sum(map(int, line.split(','))))
```

Outputs:

```
6
15
```

You may also consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package to read the file:

```
import csv                                                                      

with open('test.csv', 'r', newline='') as istr:                                 
    reader = csv.reader(istr)                                                   
    for line in reader:                                                         
        print(sum(map(int, line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('untitled6.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        total = 0
        listL = line.split(",")
        for i in listL:
            total = total + int(i)
        print(total)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.